# non cli PHPUnit - Running and collecting results in a php script

Tags: phpunit

I am trying to get the results of a php unit tests folder , but not using the CLI, and instead using a php file.

I would like to get the answer ( OK, 4 tests passed ) in a variable or something so I can decide whether the script should execute or not,  what's the best way to do this? i don't want to use batch files, I want to force the execution of the tests, inside the library itself.

I started with

require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';

When I included the tests, don't know how to start them thought.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check PHPUnits exit code, 0 means no test failed.

To run the tests from a php file, then to check the exit code, try something like this:

```
//Composer installs phpunit to /vendor/bin/phpunit
exec('/vendor/bin/phpunit', $result, $exitCode);

if ($exitCode == 0) {
  // continue exiting the script  
} else {
  // there was a test failure, more info will be in $result
}
```

If you're looking for an enterprise quality solution, look into a Continuous Integration product like Jenkins or Bamboo.

Comment: many thanks, I'll look at the continous integration frameworks

Comment: They can have a bit of a learning curve, but very worth it if you want automated deployments.  I'd go with Jenkins if you are working with a small budget, and Bamboo if you're already using JIRA.

Comment: I just reread your question and was able to provide a little more information.

Comment: Note that `$result` simply contains the output of the command, whether or not the command exited successfully.